# Menu Text Re-Adjusting On Hover

Tags: css, text, menu, hover

I have a site that has a menu that uses :hover ( like most ) in the  section.
For some reason the text just seems to get fuzzy and return to normal when hovered over. Jumping text or color changing is something I can fix since I know what it does , but right now it just gets fuzzy , like pixelated.... here are the .menu and :hover lines , would kindly ask for some help :/

```
.menu a {
display: block;
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
}        

.menu li:hover {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: Arial;
background-image: url(buttonbg.png);
font-size: 14px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
```

Its not cuzz of the border to the HOVER , the problem was there before I embedded that feature (the border)

Comment: Might be because of the background-image and text-rendering of your browser. What browser are you using? Do you have a live example or Fiddle?

Comment: Chome-
I have found that adding  -webkit-backface-visability: hidden; removes the flicker but leave the submenu buttons blurred , the flickers seems to be from the blurring of the text and it going back to normal , but I dont know how to stop it without blurring the text or disabling the hover tags.. and I cant settle with either of these options . i will try fiddle - brb

https://jsfiddle.net/rL6truu6/

Here it is , it does happen on the fiddle as well

Comment: As you're using 'skew' the browser has trouble rendering it until it has a certain position. I have had this issue before, this will be changed according to the font, try different fonts...

Comment: After trying several different fonts It seems to be less visible in some cases but still appears and i can still catch it.... The theme of the site is Diagonal so I had to use SKEW , and counter SKEW to keep the text in check :/ is there a way to skew the button and keep the text ok without having to enter a counter value of the other one ? example 
button {  
    skew(25deg)
}
text {
skew(-25deg)
}
?

Comment: I understand, this is a browser issue, you need to take the skew off the text, for example add a <div class="skewBox"></div> in the same parent as the text in HTML and style the skew in that box, not so semantic but practical in your case.

Comment: Will that solve the issue ? I think the div might make things complicated when zooming in and out.... still im gonna experiment and stuff, opening my back up folder for an update :D thanks for the info , ill let u know how it went after 30 mins or so

Comment: Yes that is most probably the solution if you really need to use skew there. As your text doesn't need to be skewed it's best to not include it in the parent of skew, so the text won't get affected but the box itself.

Comment: I found a font that is quick to render and also stated the TRANSFORM to 0.1s so its barely visible , if i didnt knew about it i wouldnt be seeing it :P if its an issue when turning the site in , i will try with the div , thanks pal you helped out big time :)

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for the update, and glad to help! Ochin Xorosho...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nima , we found 2 work around methods

1st - Change fonts to ones that take less to render and reduce the transform time on the CSS to 0.1s or 0.2s. The flicker becomes so short that its barely visible.

```
.submenu li {
transition: .1s ease-out transform;
}

.menu {
font-family: Sansation Light; }
```

2st - Removing the flicker in general with a DIV. Create a DIV for the buttons alone and exclude the text from the Skew in general so it wont be going back and forth.

No code for this one , I used the quicker solution for me.